# selecting checkbox value in cakephp

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I am loading default values for my form from another model and loading them like this

```
<?=$this->Form->input('TimeAlgo.association', array('type' => 'text','value'=>$defaults['TimeAlgoDefault']['association']))?>
```

But I have check box to load by default value I have it in my form like this

```
<?=$this->Form->input('TimeAlgo.day_time', array('type' => 'radio','options'=>array('day'=>'Day','time'=>'Time')))?>
```

Kindly tell me how to load one of its value i.e day, time that is in

```
`$defaults['TimeAlgoDefault']['dayTime']`
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get the "" opening an closing brackets nor the missing ";" at the end, but the default option is set like this:

```
$this->Form->input('TimeAlgo.day_time', array(
                                  'type' => 'radio',
                                  'options'=>array('day'=>'Day','time'=>'Time'),
                                  'default' => 'Day'
                   ));
```

[Check the documentation out](http://api13.cakephp.org/class/form-helper#method-FormHelperinput).

If you would like to set an emtry selection for a select field for example, you could use the

```
empty
```

key.

Answer (score 0):

always try to set default values from the controller level

```
if (!empty($this->data)) {
    //process form
} else {
    $this->data['ModelName']['fieldName'] = 'defaultvalue';
}
```

that is cleaner than doing it in the view - 
especially with more dynamic forms